# Come out of a function after an event in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, socket.io

I have written this function which simulates a traffic signal on a webpage using javascript. Using set interval it repeats every 20 seconds. Now i need to exit from the function when there is an event more specifically a message sent by server using socket.io . Now I know that I can just clear the interval so the function is not repeated again however it doesnot stop at that very instant, which is what I need. Is it possible to do this?

```js
(function startlights(){

            socket.on('emergency', function(msg){   // I need to exit //startLights function when 'emergency' event occurs
               console.log("mayhem  "+msg);
            });


            setTimeout(function(){
                r1.css("background-color", "black");
                g1.css("background-color","green");
                r4.css("background-color", "red");
                y4.css("background-color","black");
            },1000);
            setTimeout(function(){
                g1.css("background-color","black");
                y1.css("background-color","yellow");
            },5000);
            setTimeout(function(){
                r1.css("background-color", "red");
                y1.css("background-color","black");
                r2.css("background-color", "black");
                g2.css("background-color","green");
            },6000);
            setTimeout(function(){
                y2.css("background-color","yellow");
                g2.css("background-color","black");
            },10000);
            setTimeout(function(){
                y2.css("background-color","black");
                r2.css("background-color", "red");
                g3.css("background-color","green");
                r3.css("background-color", "black");
            },11000);
            setTimeout(function(){
                y3.css("background-color","yellow");
                g3.css("background-color", "black");
                
            },15000);
            setTimeout(function(){
                y3.css("background-color","black");
                r3.css("background-color", "red");
                g4.css("background-color","green");
                r4.css("background-color", "black");
            },16000);
            setTimeout(function(){
                y4.css("background-color","yellow");
                g4.css("background-color", "black");
            },20000);

       }());

      var repeatLights = setInterval(startlights,20000);
```

Comment: It happens because of setTimeout calls. That functions will be triggered on given timeouts because you not clear that timeouts even if you clear the repeatLights timer.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand why it ran the way it did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store the results of `setTimeout()` and call `clearTimeout()` on them. For example:

```
function startlights() {
  socket.on('emergency', function(msg) {
    for (var i = 0; i < timeouts.length; ++i)
      clearTimeout(timeouts[i]);
    clearInterval(repeatLights);
    console.log('mayhem  ' + msg);
  });

  var timeouts = [
    setTimeout(function() {
      r1.css("background-color", "black");
      g1.css("background-color","green");
      r4.css("background-color", "red");
      y4.css("background-color","black");
    }, 1000),

    setTimeout(function() {
      g1.css("background-color","black");
      y1.css("background-color","yellow");
    }, 5000),

    setTimeout(function() {
      r1.css("background-color", "red");
      y1.css("background-color","black");
      r2.css("background-color", "black");
      g2.css("background-color","green");
    }, 6000),

    setTimeout(function() {
      y2.css("background-color","yellow");
      g2.css("background-color","black");
    }, 10000),

    setTimeout(function() {
      y2.css("background-color","black");
      r2.css("background-color", "red");
      g3.css("background-color","green");
      r3.css("background-color", "black");
    }, 11000),

    setTimeout(function() {
      y3.css("background-color","yellow");
      g3.css("background-color", "black");
    }, 15000),

    setTimeout(function() {
      y3.css("background-color","black");
      r3.css("background-color", "red");
      g4.css("background-color","green");
      r4.css("background-color", "black");
    }, 16000),

    setTimeout(function() {
      y4.css("background-color","yellow");
      g4.css("background-color", "black");
    }, 20000)
  ];
}

var repeatLights = setInterval(startlights, 20000);
```

I should also point out that you will want to either only add an `'emergency'` event handler *once* *or* remove any existing `'emergency'` event handlers at the start of `startlights()`, otherwise you will continually add a new `'emergency'` event handler every time `startlights()` is called.